# Grails new Domain object with property map not setting property

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

EDIT: Per my answer below, this seems fixed by a "grails clean".  You bang your head in frustration and you overlook the obvious sometimes.

For some time we've had the following structure of domain objects:

```
abstract class Company {

String name
...
}
```

and multiple children similar to the following all with different "owner" objects.  Each concrete class has it's own table in the DB.

```
class CompanyChild extends Company {
static belongsTo = [owner:SomeDomain]
...
}
```

I'm adding another property to the abstract parent for various reasons, so the parent now looks more like the following (CompanyType is an enum):

```
abstract class Company {

String name
CompanyType companyType
...
}
```

This all seems pretty straightforward.  Now in company service, somewhere I'm doing this:

```
log.debug("Saving new company type=$companyType")
def company= new Company(name: 'Acme', companyType: companyType, <other properties here>)
log.debug("company object has type=${company.companyType}")
```

The log shows...

```
CompanyService Saving new company type=NONPROFIT
CompanyService company object has type=null
```

**What the heck is happening here?**  It really seems like ${company.companyType} should not be null.

If I add 
    company.companyType = companyType
after the object is created it works, but there's something I'm failing to understand.

Edit: grails version is 2.3.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you focus so much on a problem that you don't step back and thing...  maybe I need to do a full "grails clean"...

Clean and recompile seems to have been my answer.